# Kafka Consumer does not do anything

Tags: apache-kafka

**Steps:**

`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`
`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`
`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic sampleTopic`

[image]
**Then I type a number of messages on the terminal.** 
[image]
And then when I execute the following in another terminal :

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic sampleTopic --from-beginning`

**Nothing at all happens. No messages no errors.** 
[image]

Kafka Version:
[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: You can change log level from warn to debug by changing  [kafka_home]/config/tools-log4j.properties file to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have u checked your topics list whether the topic is created ?

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic sampleTopic --from-beginning
```

but in the image snippet I can see you are using **tessampleTopic** as the topic name, so it's not able to print anything in the console.

Please rectify the topic name with **sampleTopic**

Comment: @SamuraiJack
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic sampleTopic --from-beginning
Can you run this and check, I hope you are not using Kafka connect

Comment: @SamuraiJack your images and the actual commands are different so it's confusing, specially the port number

Comment: Sorry about that. Its just that I tried two different tutorials and none of them worked. I have tried both port numbers.

Comment: finally got it to work. I deleted kafka folder and installed latest kafka. 2.4 instead of 2.2

Comment: Aaah!! so nice to hear, but not sure why it was not working for 2.2, seems strange. A better logs will help to understand tools-log4j.properties with log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

Comment: Yeah. It worked a couple of months ago. I don't know what has changed. I wasted 3 hours figuring out whats wrong.  Nevermind, thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka producer doesn't immediately send messages. It creates and sends batches.

Make sure to close out of the producer prompt and try starting the consumer before the producer

Maybe even use the latest version of Kafka or pick up the APT repos for Confluent Platform, which includes Kafka, Zookeeper, and other utilities

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the command:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic sampleTopic --from-beginning
```

I hope this works !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is when your kafka bat gets corrupted. I found out the size of the file `kafka-console-consumer` is 0.
I copied it again from zip and it worked fine